# How can I print a quotation mark in C?

Tags: c, printf

In an interview I was asked

> Print a quotation mark using the `printf()` function

I was overwhelmed. Even in their office there was a computer and they told me to try it. I tried like this:

```
void main()
{
    printf("Printing quotation mark " ");
}
```

but as I suspected it doesn't compile. When the compiler gets the first `"` it thinks it is the end of string, which is not. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Remember the short section on escape characters at the beginning of that book...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print special characters explicitly in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477345/how-to-print-special-characters-explicitly-in-c)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Printing quotation mark \" ");
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Without a backslash, special characters have a natural special meaning. With a  backslash they print as they appear.

```
\   -   escape the next character
"   -   start or end of string
’   -   start or end a character constant
%   -   start a format specification
\\  -   print a backslash
\"  -   print a double quote
\’  -   print a single quote
%%  -   print a percent sign
```

The statement

```
printf("  \"  ");
```

will print you the quotes.
You can also print these special characters \a, \b, \f, \n, \r, \t and
\v with a (slash) preceeding it.

Comment: `\%` is wrong - it will be treated the same as `%`. `\'` isn't needed - you can put a quote within double quotes just like that.

Comment: Good catch.But you cant print % within double quotes. But you can print a percentile sign using %%. Like printf("%%");

Comment: You can also use `"%"` freely if it's not in the format string (e.g. `printf("print an int using %s\n", "%d")`)

Comment: @Angus why won't `\%` work for printing a single `%`?

Comment: @cokedude : The % sign inside the printf has a special meaning [Format specifier] and we cant print the "%" sign with printf("Printing the \% \n"); .. However, if you still wanted to print the % sign, you can follow the method of ugoren printf("Printing %s \n","%d"); => "%" is taken as a string and will be printed.

Comment: Including `%` in this list is pretty misleading.  Escape sequences involving backslash are relevant to all strings, and are processed by the compiler, at compile time.  But `%%` is completely different — it's only relevant to `printf` format strings, and it's handled by `printf`, at run time.

Answer (score 14):

You have to escape the quotationmark:

```
printf("\"");
```

Answer (score 10):

In the C programming language, `\` is used to print some of the special characters which have special meaning in C. Those special characters are listed below

```
\\ - Backslash
\' - Single Quotation Mark
\" - Double Quatation Mark
\n - New line
\r - Carriage Return
\t - Horizontal Tab
\b - Backspace
\f - Formfeed
\a - Bell(beep) sound
```

Answer (score 8):

Besides escaping the character, you can also use the format `%c`, and use the character literal for a quotation mark.

```
printf("And I quote, %cThis is a quote.%c\n", '"', '"');
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use *escaping* of characters. It's a solution of this chicken-and-egg problem: how do I write a ", if I need it to terminate a string literal? So, the C creators decided to use a special character that changes treatment of the next char:

```
printf("this is a \"quoted string\"");
```

Also you can use '\' to input special symbols like "\n", "\t", "\a", to input '\' itself: "\\" and so on.

Answer (score 3):

This one also works:

```
printf("%c\n", printf("Here, I print some double quotes: "));
```

But if you plan to use it in an interview, make sure you can explain what it does.

**EDIT**: Following Eric Postpischil's comment, here's a version that doesn't rely on ASCII:

```
printf("%c\n", printf("%*s", '"', "Printing quotes: "));
```

The output isn't as nice, and it still isn't 100% portable (will break on some hypothetical encoding schemes), but it should work on EBCDIC.

Comment: This is wrong.The inner printf will be executed first.Then the outer printf will be executed.Normally nested printf's are used to find the total no of characters printed in the console.

Comment: This isn't wrong, just a bit twisted, and it works very well. Try it. As you say, the inner printf is executed first, the the outer - what's  wrong with it?

Comment: It will print the ascii value of the number(no of characters printed) outputted from the inner printf.

Comment: Yes, it will print the ASCII value of the number of characters printed in the inner printf. So count them and look it up in an ASCII table.

Comment: I am tempted to vote up from amusement. However, the C standard does not specify that C uses ASCII. Thus, this answer is technically incorrect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, added a version which doesn't rely on ASCII. But it isn't as nice as the original.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char ch='"';
printf("%c",ch);
return 0;
}
```

Output: "

Answer (score 0):

you should use escape character like this:

```
printf("\"");
```

Comment: Good solution, but it's already given in other answers, and the exact same code is given in halex's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11772309/446106)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
 printf("\"Hello World\"");
 return 0;}
```

I guess that's the way. By the way, I have just started learning to program.

Comment: Yes, that is the way. As already said more than a decade ago in the selected answer. Please, when answering old questions, be sure to bring something new that was not already said back in the time

Comment: Sure, I would love to add something new in my upcoming answers as I will build up my expertise.