# C: Symbols in array of char

Tags: c, arrays, char, symbols

i need to put many symbols in one array of char.

This is my code, I have problem with the single quote symbol, " `'` " :

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int a;
    char alph[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.',',',':','?','=','-','(',')','"',''','/','%','@','!'};
}
```

Comment: Try this `'\''`. And do not forget to read about escape sequences.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11772291/2455888

Comment: Thanks! it work's for the symbol! But I want to put a word instead the  symbol in the array? It's possible?

Comment: @user3121134 Do not ask another question here, create a new one.

Comment: @user3121134: Please enter a new question, do not use edit to add a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape the quote with a backslash, i.e. `'\''`

Answer (score 1):

To represent `'` as a character, you must escape it. In C you do this by using `\` : `char c = '\''`
You don't need to escape `'` when using it inside a string (but inside string you need to escape `"`).

Comment: Characters like " **must** be escape using \ is not correct.  "The double-quote " and question-mark ? are representable either by themselves or by the escape sequences \" and \?,"  C11dr §6.4.4.4 4   `'"'` is OK.

Comment: You must escape the `"` if it's in a double-quote string.  You must escape the `'` if it's in a single-quote string (character).  You don't need to escape `'"'` or `"don't"`.

Comment: @hymie Tanks, I forgot this case. I edited my answer.