# How to print special characters explicitly in C?

Tags: c, printf

When I use below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s","Hello world\nHello world");
    return 0;
}
```

it prints as:

```
 Hello world
 Hello world
```

How can I prevent this and print it as raw string literal in C? I mean it should be displayed as it is in terminal window like below:

```
Hello world\nHello world
```

I know I can achieve this by using backslash for printf but is there any other C function or way to do this without backslashing? It would be helpful when reading files.

Comment: If you read in files that contain a backslash, you can print them with `printf` without doing anything different. Have you tried it? In your example, the compiler is interpreting the `\n` and replacing it with a newline. If you fill in your strings some other way, say by reading a line of a file into a string, this doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks. I need \n character to be displayed as raw. It defaults not to be visible and creating a new line in terminal window.

Comment: Oh, you want a newline in a string to be displayed as a `\n`? So if you read a file that contains a newline, it will replace it with a `\n`? You could write a function to do that.

Comment: Oh, is not there any standard function for that in C? Should I replace all escape characters by backslashing by a function? It sounds a bit awkward.

Comment: Well, once the text is in a string, there are no escape characters left to replace. You just have a literal newline character in your string. I'll write a short function to show what I'm thinking of.

Comment: `if(ch == '\n') fputs("\\n", stdout); else putchar(ch);`

Comment: Consider http://stackoverflow.com/a/22152332/2410359

Comment: After this string is printed, what will read it?  Just humans or other C code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism to do this.  You have to do it manually, character-by-character.  However, the functions in `ctype.h` may help.  Specifically, in the "C" locale, the function `isprint` is guaranteed to be true for all of the graphic characters in the *basic execution character set*, which is effectively the same as all the graphic characters in 7-bit ASCII, plus space; and it is guaranteed *not* to be true for all the *control* characters in 7-bit ASCII, which includes tab, carriage return, etc.

Here is a sketch:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"); // (1)

    while ((x = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        unsigned int c = (unsigned int)(unsigned char)x; // (2)

        if (isprint(c) && c != '\\')
            putchar(c);
        else
            printf("\\x%02x", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This does not escape `'` nor `"`, but it does escape `\`, and it is straightforward to extend that if you need it to.

Printing `\n` for U+000A, `\r` for U+000D, etc. is left as an exercise.  Dealing with characters outside the basic execution character set (e.g. UTF-8 encoding of U+0080 through U+10FFFF) is also left as an exercise.

This program contains two things which are not necessary with a fully standards-compliant C library, but in my experience have been necessary on real operating systems.  They are marked with `(1)` and `(2)`.

1) This explicitly sets the 'locale' configuration the way it is *supposed* to be set by default.

2) The value returned from `getchar` is an `int`.  It is *supposed* to be either a number in the range representable by `unsigned char` (normally 0-255 inclusive), or the special value `EOF` (which is *not* in the range representable by `unsigned char`).  However, buggy C libraries have been known to return negative numbers for characters with their highest bit set.  If that happens, the `printf` will print (for instance) `\xffffffa1` when it should've printed `\xa1`.  Casting `x` to `unsigned char` and then back to `unsigned int` corrects this.

Comment: Note: No need for `unsigned int c = (unsigned int)(unsigned char)x;`, just use `x`.  `getchar()` returns a value in the `unsigned char` range or `EOF`.  `x` is zero extended.

Comment: @chux You are correct as far as the standard goes, but I have personally tripped over at least two C libraries that didn't get that right. It _was_ a long time ago; perhaps the extra defensiveness is no longer necessary.

Comment: Scars from earlier battles cover my fingertips too.

Comment: Thanks @zvol for explanation. But I did not understand what is the purpose behind zero extensioning .  Why is x type casted to a char first and then int while x is already char. It will be helpful for me if the code is simpler, please, because I am new to C.

Comment: @Jessie Unfortunately, that line is necessary in practice (although, as pointed out above, not in principle).  I have added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be what you want. Run `myprint(c)` to print the character C or a printable representation of it:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void myprint(int c)
{
    if (isprint(c))
        putchar(c); // just print printable characters
    else if (c == '\n')
        printf("\\n"); // display newline as \n
    else
        printf("%02x", c); // print everything else as a number
}
```

If you're using Windows, I think all your newlines will be CRLF (carriage return, linefeed) so they'll print as `0d\n` the way I wrote that function.

Answer (score 1):

Just use,putchar(specialCharName). It displays the entered special character.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%s","Hello world\\nHello world");
    return 0;
}
```

This would produce the following output:
    Hello world\nHello world

Comment: I know I can do by backslashing. I need a way without using backslashing if possible.

Comment: There is no other way.

Comment: I agree with @IvoValchev. Do not down vote before giving a chance to explain.

Comment: @GRC There is another way.  Take a look at the answers given by yellowantphil or zwol.

Comment: both of those do the almost the same thing, they replace \n with \\n, not in string but in output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, if you have a string containing control characters like newline, tab, backspace, etc., you want to print a text representation of those characters, rather than interpret them as control characters.

Unfortunately, there's no built-in `printf` conversion specifier that will do that for you.  You'll have to walk through the string character by character, test each one to see if it's a control character, and write some text equivalent for it.

Here's a quick, lightly tested example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>
...
char *src="This\nis\ta\btest";

char *lut[CHAR_MAX] = {0};  // look up table for printable equivalents
                            // of non-printable characters
lut['\n'] = "\\n";
lut['\t'] = "\\t";
lut['\b'] = "\\b";
...
for ( char *p = src; *p != 0; p++ )
{
  if ( isprint( *p ) )
    putchar( *p );
  else
    fputs( lut[ (int) *p], stdout ); // puts adds a newline at the end,
                                     // fputs does not.
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Comment: If `char` is signed by default, the above code will fail if `src` contains any non ASCII characters.  The cast `(int) *p` does not address this issue!  You should use `UCHAR_MAX` for `lut` size and cast as `(unsigned char)` in `isprint((unsigned char)*p)` and `lut[(unsigned char)*p]`.

Comment: In typical implementations, `isprint(CHAR_MAX)` --> 0 causing  `lut[ (int) CHAR_MAX]` to access out of bounds.   `char *lut[CHAR_MAX]` is certainly off by 1.  I'd expect  `char *lut[CHAR_MAX+1]` (and somehow handle negative values) or even better `char *lut[UCHAR_MAX+1]` and use `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you the user **[@chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux)** for contributing to the improvement this answer.

---

Why did not you write general-purpose solution? It would keep you from many problems in the future.

```
char *
str_escape(char str[])
{
    char chr[3];
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char));
    unsigned int len = 1, blk_size;

    while (*str != '\0') {
        blk_size = 2;
        switch (*str) {
            case '\n':
                strcpy(chr, "\\n");
                break;
            case '\t':
                strcpy(chr, "\\t");
                break;
            case '\v':
                strcpy(chr, "\\v");
                break;
            case '\f':
                strcpy(chr, "\\f");
                break;
            case '\a':
                strcpy(chr, "\\a");
                break;
            case '\b':
                strcpy(chr, "\\b");
                break;
            case '\r':
                strcpy(chr, "\\r");
                break;
            default:
                sprintf(chr, "%c", *str);
                blk_size = 1;
                break;
        }
        len += blk_size;
        buffer = realloc(buffer, len * sizeof(char));
        strcat(buffer, chr);
        ++str;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

---

### How it work!

```
int
main(const int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    puts(str_escape("\tAnbms\n"));
    puts(str_escape("\tA\v\fZ\a"));
    puts(str_escape("txt \t\n\r\f\a\v 1 \t\n\r\f\a\v tt"));
    puts(str_escape("dhsjdsdjhs hjd hjds "));
    puts(str_escape(""));
    puts(str_escape("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\f\a\v"));
    puts(str_escape("\x0b\x0c\t\n\r\f\a\v"));
    puts(str_escape("\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14"));
}
```

### Output

```
\tAnbms\n
\tA\v\fZ\a
txt \t\n\r\f\a\v 1 \t\n\r\f\a\v tt
dhsjdsdjhs hjd hjds 

0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\f\a\v
\v\f\t\n\r\f\a\v
\a\b\t\n\v\f\r
```

This solution based on an information from the Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences
and the answers other users of the stackoverflow.com.

---

### Testing environment

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: 1) For a _general_ solution, the answer should also show how it handles printing a `char` outside the 0-127 range.  2) `strcat(buffer, chr);` is UB as `buffer[]` is not initialized.

Comment: Dear @chux, why are you need an answer on "how it handles printing a char outside the 0-127 range?" and why "buffer[] is not initialized?" - I don`t no errors and no warnings about it. I am used for compilation the GCC on GNU/Linux (I updated answer).

Comment: 1) What is the value of `buffer[0]` the first time `strcat(buffer, chr);` is called?  Code does not set it anywhere, so it is uninitialized.  2) The space allocated is 1 too small.

Comment: @chux, may be you are right. Each string always contains the last character '\0'. I updated the answer and added You as a contributor on top the of the content.

Comment: "Each string always contains the last character '\0'", but `buffer` is not necessarily a _string_.  Code never puts a `'\0'` in `buffer[]` before calling `strcat(buffer, chr)`, so that leads to undefined behavior (UB).  Simply add `buffer[0] = '\0';` after `char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char));`.

Comment: @chunk, I think your notice is very advanced, but I don`t this technique at all early and never faced with the UB or other undesirable side effects. I read many resources in web, but never heard about "buffer[0] = '\0'". Where did you find? - a link on an article,a  book, a page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /// My experience Win 10 Code blocks GCC MinGW

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
///#include <threads.h>
#include <conio.h>
/// #include <dos.h>
#include <direct.h>

int main(void)

{
  /// This will give your desired result, turn string into Raw string :
  printf(R"(Hello world\nHello world)");
  printf(R"(Raw string support printing  *&^%$#@!~()_+-=,<.>/?:;"' )");
  printf("\n");
  printf(R"(.C with a Capital C file format does not support raw string )");
  printf("\n");
  printf(R"(.c with a small c file format does support raw string )");
  printf("\n");
  printf(R"( Raw string did not support \n new line )");
  printf("\n");

  printf(
      R"(More reading material at - https: // en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Raw_strings;)");
  printf("\n");
  printf(
      R"(More reading material at - https: // en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal;)");
  printf("\n");
  printf(
      R"(More reading material at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850244/does-c-support-raw-string-literals;)");
  printf("\n");
  printf(
      R"(More reading material at - https: // learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-string-literals?view=vs-2019)");
  printf("\n");
  printf(
      R"(More reading material at-https: // learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/string-literal-concatenation?view=vs-2019)");
  printf("\n");
  /// Raw string.

    printf(R"(More reading material at - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/const-qualifier-in-c/;)");
  printf("\n");
  
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro just use this simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     printf("Hello World\\nHello World");
     return 0;
}
```

And it should work pretty fine !
Happy Coding