# How to print "\" on C

Tags: c

I am trying to save in a char the symbol "\" and later print it but I can't.

Any good idea?

```
char direction = '\';
printf("%c", direction);
```

Comment: C11 [§6.4.4.4 Character constants](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4).

Answer (score 9):

Escape it.

```
char direction = '\\';
```

Answer (score 9):

You can directly print like this:

```
printf("\\");
```

for print any special character.

```
\\ - Backslash
\' - Single Quotation Mark
\" - Double Quotation Mark
\? - Question Mark
\n - New line
\r - Carriage Return
\t - Horizontal Tab
\b - Backspace
\f - Formfeed
\a - Bell (beep sound)
\v - Vertical Tab
```

ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11792217/5747242

C11 [§6.4.4.4 Character constants](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4) and [§5.2.2 Character display semantics](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.2) also help.

Comment: I can never remember if \a is universally supported or is an option. Note also that `\?` is needed optionally for `?` to escape trigraphs.

Comment: The alert (`'\a'`) has been standard C since the beginning, @Bathsheba.  It vies with `\v` for the "least useful escape sequence" trophy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, and `\?` too surely? I shall endeavour to remember `\a` being standard from now on.

Comment: @Bathsheba: The `\?` has a purpose because of trigraphs — which are  ignored by most people and many compilers.  For example, if you write `printf("What??!\n");`, you should see `What|` on the output if your compiler heeds trigraphs — and `What??!` if it doesn't.  GCC requires `-trigraphs` to pay attention to them.  The standard says it should happen all the time.  I believe C++ finally said "there are no trigraphs any more".  To get the sequence I wanted, in Standard C (with trigraphs), I'd write `printf("What\?\?!\n");` — though only one of the two `\?` sequences is sufficient.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Indeed, trigraphs are removed from C++17. Sad time indeed for the obfsucators. My understanding is that in C, trigraphs are substituted before the preprocessor.

Comment: @Bathsheba: C11 [§5.1.1.2 Translation phases](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2): Trigraphs are removed when newlines are added in Step 1 — so that backslash-newline processing can proceed in Step 2, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use '\\'. The backslash it's the escape character.